# HOW TO invoke application_helper's method in a specific CategoryHelper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

for the purpose of reuse i put some method on applciation_helper,now i want to invoke this method on a specific helper like CategoryHelper,

is i need do something else?

```
Application_helper.rb
def ad_materials(a)
   do sth
end


CategoryHelper.rb
ad_materials("dd")#this method define on application_helper,but it didnt' work
```

is this a commany way to use common method put them in application_helper or any other recommend way,hope someone could give me a hand,thanks

i have re-edited the question,to make it clear,hope someone help again

Answer (score 1):

If you call `helper :all` in your `application_controller`, then any helper will be available in any view.

Example:

app/helpers/application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def helper(object)
    object.to_s
  end
end
```

app/controllers/application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper :all
end
```

app/views/other_objects/show.html.erb

```
<%= helper(other_object) %>
```

Is this what you are asking?

Comment: i define helper method on application_helper.rb,and i want to invoke this helper method in another xxx_helper,it's still didn't work after i add helper:all on application_controller

Comment: You want to call a helper from another helper in a separate file?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter where you put the helpers in terms of how your application finds them. But you do need to define and end your helpers such as

```
def ad_materials("dd")
    do stuff here
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying "how do I invoke a ApplicationHelper methods from CategoryHelper" I've ran into this problem. My less than elegant workaround was this:

```
module ReusableHelpers
  def ad_materials(a)
    do sth
  end
end

module ApplicationHelper
  ...
  include ReusableHelpers

  ...
end

module CategoryHelper
  include ReusableHelpers

  def show_pastries_only    
    ad_materials("cherry")
  end
end
```